# R Shiny renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a table for selected columns
with select input.
updateSelectInput is used to get the values in boxes as per selected condition.
However the rendertable is not creating a correct table on the dataset.

ui.R

```
selectInput('pick_recon',
                                    label = 'Select Recon',
                                  choices = unique(as.character(my_data$ReconIdName)),selected = "A", multiple = FALSE),
                        selectInput('pick_status',
                                    label = 'Select Status',
                                   choices = NULL),
                        selectInput("pick_rundate","Select Run Date",choices = NULL),
                        dataTableOutput("issuesbyReconName"),
```

server.R

```
observe({
    #print(input$pick_recon)
    x <- my_data$Status[my_data$ReconIdName == input$pick_recon]
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_status","Select Status",choices = unique(x))

  })

  observe({
    rundate <- my_data$RunDate[my_data$Status == input$pick_status]
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_rundate","Run Date",choices = rundate)
  })

  filterData <- reactive({
    my_dataframe[which(my_dataframe$rundate == input$pick_rundate),]
    print(filterData)
  })

output$issuesbyReconName <- renderDataTable({
datatable(filterData(),selection="single",rownames = F)

})
```

The renderdatatable is not populating a correct table on selected conditions.
Can you please help me with the data frame creation part of this code?

Thanks,

Comment: Care to make a small, reproducible example?

Comment: Can't help you properly without reproducible example. However, how about you remove `print(filterData)` from your reactive?

Comment: 'output$issuesbyReconName <- renderDataTable({
    my_data <- read.csv("data/reconIssueData.csv", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
    my_data <- my_data[my_data$RunDate == input$pick_rundate]},
    options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), c('10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100')),
                   pageLength = 20,searching = FALSE
    )) '                                                                                                           I am just able to filter the data on rundate-not on the preselected status and recon.